# Склоняется ли название города Сортавала?

Tags: орфография, склонение, топонимика

Склоняется ли название города Сортавала? Иногда даже в прессе встречаются варианты: **в Сортавале, из Сортавалы** и т. д. В то же время некоторые жители этого прекрасного карельского города говорят о том, что название не склоняется.

Answer (score 5):

Название города склоняется как сущ. 1 скл., так как оканчивается на безударный гласный А.

Например:

Главной  достопримечательностью Сортавалы остается, конечно, неповторимая по своей красоте природа и самое большое европейское озеро под названием Ладога.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

С ударением на первом слоге в многосложном названии  слово в большей степени похоже на иноязычное, в этом случае в систему склонения русского языка название уже не выписвается столь очевидно, как в случае с ударением на предпоследнем слоге.

Грамматическая справка

ИНОЯЗЫЧНЫЕ ТОПОНИМЫ на безударные гласные А и Ы могут склоняться или не склоняться: приехать из Хиросимы, на острове Куба  – на Кубе,  выставка в Осаке и в Осака. Топоним может иметь  РАЗНЫЙ РОД  для склоняемого и несклоняемого вариантов: современная Осака и современный Осака.

Примеры

Многие компании имеют в Осака филиалы. Замок в Осаке играл ключевую роль в японской истории.  Осака приобрела еще более современный вид. Современный Осака можно разделить на две части: исторический юг и деловой север.

Answer (score 3):

> ...некоторые жители этого прекрасного карельского города говорят о
>   том, что название не склоняется.

Вы правы: некоторые не склоняют, что подтверждается и Гугл-книгами.

См.: 
["из Сортавала"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22), ["в Сортавала"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=%22%D0%B2%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%22&tbm=bks)...

Но чаще *Сортавала* склоняется. У Зализняка ("Грамматический словарь русского языка") -- ***Сортавала***, (из) **Сортавалы**, (в) **Сортавалу**…

И с ударением не всё ладно...

Наиболее распространено ударение в слове *Сортавала* на третьем слоге: *Сортав**а**ла*. Но местными жителями (как отмечено в словаре Зализняка) используется и вариант названия этого города с ударением на первом слоге: *С**о**ртавала.*

=======================

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Интересно то, что Ф. Л. Агеенко в *"Словаре собственных имён русского языка"* даёт (в отличие от Зализняка) только вариант произношения слова *Сортавала* с ударением на первом слоге.

Она это слово склоняет. [См.](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F1%EE%F0%F2%E0%E2%E0%EB%E0&all=x):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

По законам единого пространства все названия российских городов склоняются (исключения есть: Сочи, Челны и др.), и у Сортавалы для самоотвода причин нет, как нет причин у Костомукши, Калевалы, Ухты. Некоторые жители этого прекрасного карельского города не правы, потому что в первую очередь он — город РФ.