# склонение иноязычных топонимов

Tags: топонимика

Здравствуйте! Склоняются ли финские названия городов в Карелии - Сортавала, Лахденпохья и Питкяранта? Спасибо.

Comment: А чем финские лучше или хуже немецких бургов, к примеру? Они — финские названия российских городов.

Answer (score 2):

По правилам финские топонимы не должны склоняться, но некоторые из них (в частности, Сортавала) *очень хотят*

[image: Сортавала]

[image: Лахденпохья]

Comment: К чему тут фотки, я не понял. А в принципе - да, аборигены всегда оригинальничают.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Жители Сортавалы неправы. Название города – существительное первого (по школьной грамматике) склонения: Сортавала, Сортавалы, Сортавале и т. д. (См., например, словарь-справочник Е. А. Левашова «Географические названия», словарь Ф. Л. Агеенко «Собственные имена в русском языке», «Грамматический словарь русского языка» А. А. Зализняка и др. издания)."

P.S. По тому же правилу склоняется и город Питкяранта. Склоняемый вариант представлен на сайте Грамота.ру, в словаре Ф. Л. Агеенко «Собственные имена в русском языке».

См. также здесь: [Склоняется ли название города Сортавала?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/416746/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b0)